# Ember JS Router not filtering when I change the controller from default

Tags: ember.js

My router in it's entirety:

```
Books.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('books', { path: '/' }, function () {
        this.route('search', { path: 'search/:keyword' });
    });
});

Books.BooksRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return this.store.find('book');
    },
    actions: {
        postAlert: function (msg, classes) {
            var postAlert = $('#alert');

            postAlert.html(msg).toggleClass(classes).toggle(1000);
            setTimeout(function () {
                postAlert.toggle(1000, function () {
                    postAlert.toggleClass(classes)
                });
            }, 3000);
        }
    }
});

Books.BooksIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return this.modelFor('books');
    },
    renderTemplate: function () {
        this.render({ controller: 'books' });
    }
});

Books.BooksSearchRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        return this.store.filter('book', function (book) {
            return book.get('titleSlug').indexOf(params.keyword) > -1;
        })
    },
    renderTemplate: function (controller) {
        this.render('books/index', { controller: controller });
    }
});
```

Now let's focus on the last bit of the router, the BooksSearchRoute. When I leave my router as it is right now and go to the route localhost/#/search/the_adventures_of_huckleberry_finn then I will see the books/index template populated with the model where the titleSlug contained the dynamic segment which is great, exactly what I expect.

Now when I try to use an action defined in my books controller from that URL I get an error that nothing handled the action. In response to that I switched the renderTemplate line so that it uses 'books' as the controller instead of the default controller.

```
renderTemplate: function () {
    this.render('books/index', { controller: 'books' });
}
```

That change allows me to access the actions in the books controller that I need. However after making the change the filter does not appear to work anymore as all of the books in the libray are displayed rather than just thouse matching the search term. Can someone please explain to me what is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is actually the expected behaviour.

#### Explanation

When a `Route` is hit, it obtains the model and passes that to the `Controller` associated with that route. It determines which one using the [Ember naming conventions](http://emberjs.com/guides/concepts/naming-conventions/).

*Override template*

What you have done here is override `renderTemplate` here to specify that a different template should be used, than the one that the naming conventions tell it to use.

That works fine in this case because the model for the `BooksIndexRoute` and the model for the `BooksSearchRoute` are compatible - they are both arrays of `Book`s.

*Override template AND controller*

The next thing that you did was to override `renderTemplate` here to specify that a different template should be used, and it should use a different controller too, `BooksController`, according to the naming convention.

Of course, `BooksController` doesn't know that you have done this, and will use the model that it is aware of, the model returned by its own `Route`, which is this case was `this.store.find('book')`.

... and since that model is not filtered, the template renders the full set of `Book` models.

#### Suggested solution

You can probably continue along this path, where you override the template and controller, and refactor the required actions such that they are available on both controllers. However, I would not suggest this, as it goes against the grain of how Ember was designed, plus it will involve quite a lot of spaghetti code.

The canonical solution would involve using the routes and controllers that you already have, but **do not** override `renderTemplate` in `BooksIndexRoute`.

Instead, extract the code that renders your list of books into a separate template and put it into a folder called `partials`, then invoke that partial from both the templates:

- from `books` (or `books\index` as the case may be), as well as
- from `books\search`

The [syntax looks like this](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/#toc_the-code-partial-code-helper)

I do not know what your templates look like, but if you post them, I can show you how to do so.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks! I'll work on using the partials tomorrow and see how it goes from there.

Comment: Okay I have attempted to convert this to use partials however now I am unable to access the BooksController actions from either the books/index or books/search routes. I assume because they are using the BooksIndexController and BooksSearchController respectivly, both of which I have not and do not want to define as the BooksController has all of the actions they need and I don't want identical actions in 3 different controllers. I don't know how to post the code here in a comment, it says that it is too long by over 4000 characters.

Comment: Without looking at your code, what I would suggest is that you make `BooksSearchController` extend `BooksIndexController` instead of `Ember.ArrayCOntroller`, or create a mixin containing the shared actions and mix it into to both controllers. There are a number of different ways you can approach this - you don't need to post all of your code, but if you post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) on jsbin, that would work well.

Comment: Extending the BooksController worked great! Thanks again